# Случайный вывод товаров

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Добрый день! 
Решил сделать случайный вывод товаров из БД для интернет-магазина, вывод производить в карточке товара.
Но вот не уверен что этот запрос безопасный и правильный:

```
"SELECT * FROM products WHERE id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5 "
```

Может ли этот запрос вывести на одной карточки товара два одинаковых товара? Может что-то подскажите получше. Вот еще видел что делают: С этим товаром также покупают...

Answer (score 4):

По поводу "два одинаковых товара".

Вот у тебя есть коробка карандашей, по одному каждого цвета.
Ты их перемешал, и берешь первые 5 штук.
Может так получиться, что у тебя все 5 оказались красными?

По поводу " подскажите получше".

В принципе, этот запрос не самый оптимальный. И если товаров десятки тысяч или больше, то будет притормаживать. Способы ускорить есть, но все очень разные, зависят от конкретного случая. Так что пока лучше оставить как есть, и заморочиться, когда запрос начнет выполняться дольше 0,01 сек.

По поводу "С этим товаром также покупают".

В 99% магазинов в эту секцию кладут залежалый товар, который надо побыстрее сбыть.
Если хочется сделать по написанному, то - сюрприз! - надо записывать все покупки в отдельную таблицу и искать по ней товары, которые покупали вместе с этим. Если нужны подробности, то следует помнить правило "одна проблема - один вопрос".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Если Вам не сложно, покажите, пожалуйста, как можно ускорить запрос, более лучшим способом по Вашему мнению. Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: [Здесь](http://sqlinfo.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=11053#p11053) есть пара способов альтернативы order by rand()

Comment: @retvizan, Спасибо.